# System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'data source'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment

I have publish my MVC 5 application on a dedicated server but getting above mentioned error. I have tried all possibilities in the web config but still unable to resolve it.

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="DataMasterEntities" connectionString="Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=DataMaster;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=***;Password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you set your `providerName` to [`EntityClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient(v=vs.110).aspx) which does not support `Data Source` keyword. Try setting your provider to `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Comment: Hi Vivi thanks for prompt reply, but i have used the original Connection string also which looks like yours and then changed the Database, user id and pwd but still same error.

Comment: Hi Alex, i have tried this solution also but than it gives a very long error saying the edmx related

Comment: @Guri: Follow these steps in my answer and it should work fine.

Comment: Yes i am doing this, but unable to connect to sql server. Again dont know why. I have Sql Server 2008 on server with SQLEXPRESS as instance name. Unable to connect when i directly connect on server using Remote Desktop but unable to connect when i connect it from my local machine.

Comment: @Guri : First try to connect to local machine sql server

Comment: unable to do so, but when i connect the server through Remote and run Studio within, sql sever will connect

Comment: i have done some changes in connection string and the new error is:-

Comment: The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and

Comment: that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're using Entity Framework. The connection string should look something like this :

```
<connectionStrings> 
  <add name="DataMasterEntities" connectionString=
     "metadata=.\DataMaster.csdl|.\DataMaster.ssdl|.\DataMaster.msl;
      provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
      provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=SERVER\SQL2000;Initial Catalog=DataMaster;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False&quot;" 
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />      
</connectionStrings>
```

Entity framework connection string is automatically generated when you create an `.edmx` file following below steps :

> 1. Right Click on Some folder in project
> 2. Add -> New Item
> 3. Under `data` select `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` and give it some name.
> 4. Select `Generate from Database` and click `Next`
> 5. Click `New Connection` button and using SQL server credentials connect to your database
> 6. Now click `Finish`. This would automatically create the connection string in `Web.Config` in above format.